# Get ComboBox Value, and use it

Tags: c#, listview, combobox

guys, I need some help! I have on my IHM several combo boxes whose data come from each of the different tables in PhpMyAdmin. I would like that when I press my `search` button, the program takes into consideration the values of the combo box entered beforehand by the user to go and retrieve them in the DATABASE and thus display them in my List view.
I decided to create a table with 2 lines. The first has the name of the combo box and the second the content. And  I don't know if is the greatest solution.

> Here is the form :

[image: Form]

> Here is my existing code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
namespace PROJET_FINDER
{
    public partial class Recherche : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
    {
        public Recherche()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Datasource = localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=");

        private void Recherche_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)//Début des appels des ComboBox
        {

            try
            {
                string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM cdh.etat";                                                     //Début Try/Catch pour le ComboBox le Code d'Etat
                connection.Open();                                                                                      //Connexion à la base de donnée ouverte
                CodeEtatFS_ComboBox_Home.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;                                    //ReadOnly sur la comboBox
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);                                       //Création de l'objet de la commande SQL
                MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();                                                       //Déclaration de la nouvelle instance
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    CodeEtatFS_ComboBox_Home.Items.Add(reader.GetString("Lib_Code_Etat"));
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (MySqlException cn)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(cn.Message);
                connection.Close();
            }
            try                                                                                                         //Début Try/Catch pour le ComboBox du numéro FS 
            {
                connection.Open();
                NuméroFS_ComboBox_Home.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;                                      //ReadOnly sur la comboBox
                string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM cdh.fiche";
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
                MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    NuméroFS_ComboBox_Home.Items.Add(reader.GetString("FS"));
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (MySqlException cn)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(cn.Message);
                connection.Close();
            }
            try                                                                                                         //Début Try/Catch pour le ComboBox des catégorie Radio
            {
                connection.Open();
                CatégorieRadiologique_ComboBox_Home.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;                        //ReadOnly sur la comboBox
                string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM cdh.ctg_rad";
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
                MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    CatégorieRadiologique_ComboBox_Home.Items.Add(reader.GetString("Radiologique"));
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (MySqlException cn)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(cn.Message);
                connection.Close();
            }
            try                                                                                                         //Début Try/Catch pour le ComboBox des Centres
            {
                connection.Open();
                Centre_ComboBox_Home.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;                                        //ReadOnly sur la comboBox
                string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM cdh.site_centre";
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
                MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Centre_ComboBox_Home.Items.Add(reader.GetString("Centre"));
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (MySqlException cn)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(cn.Message);
                connection.Close();
            }
            try                                                                                                         //Début Try/Catch pour le ComboBox des producteurs du déchet
            {
                connection.Open();
                Producteur_ComboBox_Home.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;                                    //ReadOnly sur la comboBox
                string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM cdh.prod";
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
                MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Producteur_ComboBox_Home.Items.Add(reader.GetString("Producteur"));
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (MySqlException cn)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(cn.Message);
                connection.Close();
            }
            try                                                                                                         //Début Try/Catch pour le ComboBox du conditionnement du déchet
            {
                connection.Open();
                Conditionnement_ComboBox_Home.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;                               //ReadOnly sur la comboBox
                string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM cdh.statut_condition";
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
                MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Conditionnement_ComboBox_Home.Items.Add(reader.GetString("Conditionnement"));
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (MySqlException cn)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(cn.Message);
                connection.Close();
            }
            try                                                                                                         //Début Try/Catch pour le ComboBox de la station de destination du déchet
            {
                connection.Open();
                StationDestination_ComboBox_Home.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;                            //ReadOnly sur la comboBox
                string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM cdh.station_destination";
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
                MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    StationDestination_ComboBox_Home.Items.Add(reader.GetString("Station_Destination"));
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (MySqlException cn)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(cn.Message);
                connection.Close();
            }
        }//Fin des appels des ComboBox

        private void DataTimePicker_Home_1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)                                     //Lorsque la valeur du DataTimePicker_Home_1 change alors le 3 et le 4 se désactive
        {
            DataTimePicker_Home_3.Enabled = false;
            DataTimePicker_Home_4.Enabled = false;
            if(DataTimePicker_Home_3.Enabled == false)
            {

            }
        }

        private void DataTimePicker_Home_2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)                                     //Lorsque la valeur du DataTimePicker_Home_2 change alors le 3 et le 4 se désactive
        {
            DataTimePicker_Home_3.Enabled = false;
            DataTimePicker_Home_4.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void DataTimePicker_Home_3_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)                                     //Lorsque la valeur du DataTimePicker_Home_3 change alors le 1 et le 2 se désactive
        {
            DataTimePicker_Home_1.Enabled = false;
            DataTimePicker_Home_2.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void DataTimePicker_Home_4_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)                                     //Lorsque la valeur du DataTimePicker_Home_4 change alors le 1 et le 2 se désactive
        {
            DataTimePicker_Home_1.Enabled = false;
            DataTimePicker_Home_2.Enabled = false;
        }  

        private void Data_Reset_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)                                                //Bouton de réinitiallisation des DataTimePicker
        {
            DataTimePicker_Home_1.Enabled = true;
            DataTimePicker_Home_2.Enabled = true;
            DataTimePicker_Home_3.Enabled = true;
            DataTimePicker_Home_4.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void Chercher_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)                                                  //Déclaration du bouton RECHERCHER
        {
            Object selectedItem_Etat = CodeEtatFS_ComboBox_Home.SelectedItem;
            Object selectedItem_Centre = Centre_ComboBox_Home.SelectedItem;
            Object selectedItem_CatRadg = CatégorieRadiologique_ComboBox_Home.SelectedItem;
            Object selectedItem_FS = NuméroFS_ComboBox_Home.SelectedItem;
            Object selectedItem_StationdeDestination = StationDestination_ComboBox_Home.SelectedItem;
            Object selectedItem_Producteur = Producteur_ComboBox_Home.SelectedItem;
            Object selectedItem_Conditionnement = Conditionnement_ComboBox_Home.SelectedItem;

            object[,] Tab_ComboBox =
           {
                {selectedItem_Etat, CodeEtatFS_ComboBox_Home},

                {selectedItem_Centre, Centre_ComboBox_Home},

                {selectedItem_FS, NuméroFS_ComboBox_Home},

                {selectedItem_CatRadg, CatégorieRadiologique_ComboBox_Home},

                {selectedItem_StationdeDestination, StationDestination_ComboBox_Home},

                {selectedItem_Producteur, Producteur_ComboBox_Home},

                {selectedItem_Conditionnement, Conditionnement_ComboBox_Home}
            };



            int i = 0;

            bool statement = false;


            while (i == 7)
            {
                connection.Open();
                if (selectedItem_Etat != null)
                {
                    LW_FS_Home.Items.Clear();
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM etat WHERE Lib_Code_Etat=@Lib_Code_Etat", connection);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lib_Code_Etat", CodeEtatFS_ComboBox_Home.Text);//Récupération de l'age souhaité par l'utilisateur
                    statement = true;
                    i++;
                }
                else if (selectedItem_Centre != null)
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM cdh.site_centre WHERE Centre=@Centre", connection);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lib_Code_Etat", Centre_ComboBox_Home.Text);
                    statement = true;
                    i++;
                }
                else if (selectedItem_FS != null)
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM cdh.fiche WHERE FS=@NuméroFS_ComboBox_Home", connection);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lib_Code_Etat", NuméroFS_ComboBox_Home.Text);
                    statement = true;
                    i++;
                }
                else if (selectedItem_CatRadg != null)
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM cdh.ctg_rad WHERE Radiologique=@Radiologique", connection);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lib_Code_Etat", CatégorieRadiologique_ComboBox_Home.Text);
                    statement = true;
                    i++;
                }
                else if (selectedItem_StationdeDestination != null)
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM cdh.station_destination WHERE Station_Destination=@Station_Destination", connection);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lib_Code_Etat", StationDestination_ComboBox_Home.Text);
                    statement = true;
                    i++;
                }
                else if (selectedItem_Producteur != null)
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM cdh.prod WHERE Producteur=@Producteur", connection);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lib_Code_Etat", Producteur_ComboBox_Home.Text);
                    statement = true;
                    i++;
                }
                else if (selectedItem_Conditionnement != null)
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM cdh.statut_condition WHERE Conditionnement=@Conditionnement", connection);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lib_Code_Etat", Conditionnement_ComboBox_Home.Text); 
                    statement = true;
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("AIE");
                }

                foreach (Object Tab_Combo in Tab_ComboBox)
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                    if (statement == true)
                    {
                        using (MySqlDataReader Lire = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (Lire.Read())  // Boucle While qui regarde toutes les infos que l'on souhaite voir avec la méthode "lire"
                            {
                                string TAB = Lire["Tab_Combo"].ToString();

                                LW_FS_Home.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { TAB }));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
}
```

Thanks for the help.